# Zingchart how to add custom legend item

Tags: zingchart

I have a bar chart with 3 kinds of bar: FOO, BAR and BAZ.

Horizontal axis are quarters.

[image]

BAR and BAZ use the same series. BAR (blue) becoming BAZ (orange) after Q1-17.

```
"rules": [{
    "rule": "%kv > 1",
    "background-color":"orange"
}]
```

How can I add BAZ (orange) to the legend?

```js
zingchart.THEME = "classic";
var myConfig = {
  "graphset": [{
    "type": "bar",
    "background-color": "white",
    "plotarea": {
      "margin": "80 60 100 60",
      "y": "125px"
    },
    "legend": {
      "layout": "x3",
      "y": "13%",
      "x": "34.5%",
      "overflow": "page",
      "toggle-action": "remove",
    },
    "scale-x": {
      "labels": [
        "Q4-16",
        "Q1-17",
        "Q2-17",
        "Q3-17"
      ],
      "markers": [{
        "value-range": true,
        "range": [1.5],
        "line-color": "red",
        "line-width": 1,
        "line-style": "solid",
        "type": "line"
      }]
    },
    "series": [{
        "values": [
          37.47,
          57.59,
          45.65,
          37.43
        ],
        "background-color": "#8993c7",
        "text": "FOO"
      },
      {
        "values": [
          13.4,
          14.11,
          14.89,
          16.86
        ],
        "background-color": "blue",
        "text": "BAR",
        "rules": [{
          "rule": "%kv > 1",
          "background-color": "orange"
        }]
      }
    ]
  }]
};

zingchart.render({
  id: 'myChart',
  data: myConfig,
  height: 500,
  width: 725
});
```

```css
.zc-ref {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    zingchart.MODULESDIR = "https://cdn.zingchart.com/modules/";
    ZC.LICENSE = ["569d52cefae586f634c54f86dc99e6a9", "ee6b7db5b51705a13dc2339db3edaf6d"];
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='myChart'><a class="zc-ref" href="https://www.zingchart.com/">Charts by ZingChart</a></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So one way to do it is split up your data. The easiest way to explain this is to make another series for "BAZ" and in the first two quarters have null values.

[demo here](https://demos.zingchart.com/view/PMN49PUK)

The main reason for doing it this way is maintaining the built in legend toggling functionality. This way when you click it wont turn off the whole series (blue and orange bars.) Which I assume is the intended functionality.

If you don't mind turning off blue and orange bars at the same time you can do the following to add another legend item. Add the text and color inside the `series` object. Essentially, create a blank `series` object.

```
      ...{
        "text":"BAZ",
        "background-color":"orange"
      }...
```

non interactive legend [demo here](https://demos.zingchart.com/view/MJM88GC4)

If you are looking for something in between these two demos it will take some custom Javascript using the ZingChart API.